# How (or whether) to ask about specific products

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Is it OK to ask about specific products? Should we provide some guidelines on how to do so?

For example, I asked a question about the Dwarven Forge product [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/624/how-many-sets-of-dwarven-forge-do-i-need-to-start-with/3326#3326), which spawned both a good response from an actual user of the product, as well as some good suggestions on alternatives. However, a similar post later, discussing the Epic Words website, was attacked as being an "advertisement", so I deleted it. I still have other products I'd like to ask on, but I thought it would be good if we could get a policy / suggestions on how to phrase these kind of questions so that they're not upsetting anyone.

(This should probably be community-wiki)

Comment: For those who can see deleted posts, the Epic Words one is here: [Where can I see an example of good usage of EpicWords.com?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/where-can-i-see-an-example-of-good-usage-of-epicwords-com)

Answer (score 5):

I have no problem with folks asking about a specific product.  I don't remember the Epic Words post, it may have predated me.

If a post smells like an advertisement then I could see objecting to it, but if you are asking for opinions/reviews of a certain product I don't think that would be problematic.

Comment: Also let me add that you should trust the community process here.  One guy making douchey comments on your post isn't an "attack" you need to respond to - if five people feel the same way, your post'll get deleted.

Comment: Yes, what mxyzplk said. I noticed that deleted Epic Words post, and wondered why. I'd be in favour of re-opening it.